# Automatically fill in the login form for facebook.com

Tags: c#, facebook

How to automatically fill in the Facebook login form: username and password using c# windows form application.

I want to make the work automatic with a single button and open my Facebook page into my text field or something else. Less work, less time.

Comment: What is the problem, really?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, this is not the make-a-wish foundation, please take the time to read the site help to work out how to ask appropriate questions so we can help you

Comment: If you're trying to make an app for Facebook, this is not the correct way to go about it.

Comment: Facebook’s terms explicitly forbid you from using any such automation. _“Less work, less time.”_ - to do what exactly - spam the platform with content that doesn’t belong there in the first place? (At least that’s usually the main intention behind this kind of question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you need to learn something called web browser automation. Their is a browser automation library/tool called as Selenium. Use it to achieve your goal. I did exactly the same thing around 6 years ago.

Code below mentioned steps in your code with selenium in order and you shall achieve what you deserve. You can get selenium and more resources from [here](https://www.seleniumhq.org/).

1. Initialize selenium web driver for whatever browser you are using. I will recommend Firefox though.
2. Open the login page of Facebook.
3. Get user name textbox through its XPath and send key strokes of your user name.
4. Do the above step for password text box also.
5. Add code to simulate click on login button.